# Property overriden with "new" gets dupped in WCF Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, inheritance, serialization

I have a problem with a Webservice I'm creating, the thing is, I have a class, name it ClassA with PropertyA, he na ClassB inheriting ClassA that overrides PropertyA using "new" like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    [DataMember]
    public new int PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

This should make ClassB "replace" the string PropertyA from ClassA for a int PropertyA in ClassB.

I expose ClassB in a service method like this:

```
public bool TellMeSomething(ClassB param) { .... whatever .... }
```

When I add the service reference in the client application, the classes imported show something like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public int PropertyA1 { get; set; }
}
```

As you can notice, ClassB has no "new int PropertyA" anymore, but a "int PropertyA1". I guess the serializer finds the ancestor has a PropertyA already and doesn't know how to handle the "new" keyword to hide the "string PropertyA", so it creates a new name for the PropertyA in the inherited class...

Is there any way to avoid this behavior? I would need that property to be called like it should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *generics* instead of identifier re-using:

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassA<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public T PropertyA { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}

// No need to override PropertyA since T is int and ClassB
// inherits both PropertyA and PropertyB...
[DataContract]
public class ClassB : ClassA<int>
{
}
```

Comment: It's a possible solution when you have only one or two occurrence of this, but I have several properties that must be hidden, and I'd end with a lot of generics that would break Code Analisis rules at my company: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182129.aspx

Comment: @JoanVilariño How generics can break code analysis rules? ;)

Comment: @JoanVilariño And at the end of the day, you need to handle positive refactorings as a required action while coding... I mean, tell your boss that this is the WCF way of solving the issue!

Comment: @JoanVilariño In the worst case, you can declare the whole property with other name and treat `PropertyX` as `PropertyB` in code.......... BTW, how many classes do you need to change to use generics? And again **is using generics a bad practice?** **INCREDIBLE!**

Comment: I'm not saying using generics is a bad practice... but in my company these rules are active, and they "recommend" not to disable them.... anyway, as I said in my first reply, your solution is good. I found another way to do it without inheriting... at last, these entities are just DTOs that I'm passing to my domain layer, so I have made them separated and then mapped to a common class at my domain layer, and it's solved. Thanks!

Comment: @JoanVilariño Nice! :) Hi from Bcn